# How to make logrotate working for already existing log files?

Tags: logrotate

I have written a conf that would compress the logs daily to the maximum size of 2GB. I have allowed a total of 3 such log rotated files:

```
/var/log/upstart/*.log {
        daily
        rotate 3
    size 2G
    compress
    delaycompress
}
```

However, the directory where this file is located, it is not experiencing any log rotation. It became 10B in size.